# the zipalign tool was not found in the sdk

Tags: android, eclipse

When I want to export a signed apk, I get this message :

```
the zipalign tool was not found in the sdk
```

I've updated my sdk, my eclipse, still get it.
Then, I saw I had no file called zipalign in my sdk/tools folder.
So I copied one I had in another sdk folder, as I saw in another post.

I checked this post : [Error while running zipalign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581770/error-while-running-zipalign)
I'm exporting to the desktop, so I have rights.

I have no idea, what should I do now. It seems that this problems happens after updating sdk

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/h7JwtwmJCIM

PD: I use Mac.

Any Idea?

Comment: I had the same problem and found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24446579/2719186

Comment: Fixed ! I saw the first solution : Copying the file and it didn't work, but now I installed Android SDK Build-tools Rev. 20 and it is working! Thanks !

Comment: I already had the Build tools 20, i copied the file and it didn't work. How do you update something that is already up-to-date ?

Comment: Soon all will be on Android Studio.......

Comment: Now Zipalign tool is present at this location at /path/to/sdk/build-tools/zipalign.exe

Answer (score 156, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to `Window → Android SDK Manager`, check `Android SDK **Build-tools** Rev. 20` and then click `Install`.

After the update restart Eclipse and try again.

Comment: This worked for me; note that it requires a restart of eclipse

Comment: Yeah updated the tools v20, needed a eclipse restart. is now fine thanks!

Comment: Damn restart got me aswell